# Bamboo OnDemand: how to auto-generate snapshots?

Tags: bamboo, ondemand

I've been busy setting up our bamboo on demand instance to run the builds we previously ran on our local instance.
As many others have already posted about or created tickets for (see for example https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/109719/automated-ebs-snapshots-in-bamboo-ondemand, https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-11525, https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/AOD-3293), I'm facing the issue of outdated maven repositories on the attached EBS volume as the contents on those volumes are not automatically persisted when the EC2 instance is terminated/shut down.

Specifically, the post at https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/109719/automated-ebs-snapshots-in-bamboo-ondemand is more or less exactly what I want to achieve: automatic generation of a snapshot before shutdown so that all the build artifacts are preserved and don't need to be re-created the next time the instance starts up. However, I was unable to get it to run as suggested in the above post.

Is there anyone who has successfully tackled this issue? If so, how did you do it? If not, any ideas or pointers are greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Chris